# Размещение и работа .htaccess в подпапке

Tags: .htaccess

Есть файл .htaccess в корне сайта. Если я размещу в подпапке /images/ второй .htaccess и пропишу там стандартное кеширование файлов с расширениями .png и .jpg, то это кеширование будет распространяться только на изображения в /images/ или на все картинки сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, только на папку images и ниже.